# Good book for Local Fields/ Commutative algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am currently studying Local Fields from Serre's textbook, but finding that it requires a bit too much prior knowledge for me. Can anyone suggest another book that I can use alongside Serre that might make things a bit clearer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Local Fields](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9781139171885) by J. W. S. Cassels.